# A function that is both $U(2)$ and $O(2)$

Tags: group-theory

Let $\mathbf{u}$ be a vector:

$$
\mathbf{v}:=\pmatrix{a+bi\\c+di}
$$

I define the function $f(\mathbf{v})$:

$$
f(\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v})^*
$$

where $(\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v})^*$ is the complex conjugate of $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}$.

I am now interested in the invariant group of $f(\mathbf{v})$ under a replacement by a linear transformation $\mathbf{v}\to U\mathbf{v}$.

---

First, we note that $f(\mathbf{v})$ is $O(2)$:

$$
f(O\mathbf{v})=((O\mathbf{v})^T O\mathbf{v})((O\mathbf{v})^T O\mathbf{v})^*\\
=\mathbf{v}^TO^TO\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{v}^TO^TO\mathbf{v})^*\\
O^TO=I \implies f(O\mathbf{v})=f(\mathbf{v})
$$

---

Second, we note that $f(\mathbf{v})$ is also $U(2)$

$$
f(U\mathbf{v})=((U\mathbf{v})^TU\mathbf{v})((U\mathbf{v})^TU\mathbf{v})^*\\
=\mathbf{v}^TU^TU\mathbf{v} (\mathbf{v}^TU^TU\mathbf{v})^*\\
=\mathbf{v}^TU^TU\mathbf{v} \mathbf{v}^*U^*U^{T*}\mathbf{v}^{T*}
$$

Since $\mathbf{v} \mathbf{v}^*$ is a scalar, we move it to the left:

$$
=(\mathbf{v} \mathbf{v}^*)\mathbf{v}^TU^TUU^*U^{T*}\mathbf{v}^{T*}\\
UU^*=I \implies \\
=(\mathbf{v} \mathbf{v}^*)\mathbf{v}^TU^TU^{T*}\mathbf{v}^{T*}\\
U^TU^{T*}=I \implies  f(U\mathbf{v})=f(\mathbf{v})
$$

---

Is this correct; is $f(\mathbf{v})$ both $U(2)$ and $O(2)$?

Comment: Can you explain how you deduce from $f(O\mathbf{v})=\mathbf{v}^TO^TO\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{v}^TO^TO\mathbf{v})^*$ (for all $v$) that $O^TO=I$?

Comment: @BQT Well if $O^TO=I$ then $f(O\mathbf{v})=f(\mathbf{v})$. Is this not enough?

Comment: Did you inverse the implication direction in your post?

Comment: @BQT I believe I have, ill fix it.

Comment: A real orthogonal matrix is by definition also a unitary matrix so the second case implies the first.